# FBSDKGameRequestContent request doesn't send invite

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I try to send invitation to game round to my friends from facebook using FBSDKGameRequestContent request.

This is a code:

```
let gameContent:FBSDKGameRequestContent = FBSDKGameRequestContent.init()
gameContent.message = "Challenge Your Facebook Friends!"
gameContent.title = "MyMegaGame Caption"
FBSDKGameRequestDialog.show(with: gameContent, delegate: self)
```

But some of them didn't receive invitation.
What I do wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you not need to specify a list of recipients? Looking at the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKGameRequestContent/) `FBSDKGameRequestContent` has a property called recipients that takes user IDs, usernames or invite tokens.

Comment: @Brian if the app doesn't specify recipients, the user will get a friend selector presented to choose them themselves.

Comment: App invites will only show on platforms your app has an implementation on. So are those friends on iOS devices as well, or ...?

Comment: Did you implement any necessary delegate methods?